# plot single column binary file with gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, binaryfiles

how can I plot single column binary file with gnuplot?

This is the gnuplot command I am using:

`plot "file.bin" binary format="%float" u ($0+1):1 every ::0::999`

but I get all the points along the vertical line `x = 0`.

I am creatiing the binary file in a C code I have:

`write(fdesc, bin_data, tot_size * sizeof(double));`

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried simply plotting `plot "file.bin" binary` to see if that works?

Comment: yes I've tried and didn't work. It says "Read grid of zero width"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write double values to the binary file, you must also read doubles from gnuplot:

```
plot "file.bin" binary format="%double" u 0:1 every ::::999
```

As a more complete example, consider the following C snippet `simple.c`:

```c
#include <unistd.h>    
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int N = 128;
    double values[N];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    values[i] = i * i;

    write(STDOUT_FILENO, values, N*sizeof(double));
}
```

Compile that with `gcc simple.c`, open `gnuplot` and type

```
plot '< ./a.out' binary format='%double' using 0:1
```